# Short animated film where a subway runs through a boy's bedroom

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I am looking for a short film. It wasn't very long—probably under 30 minutes. In it, a subway runs through a boy's bedroom. He complains to city officials, who tell him that their computer, which "is never wrong," placed the subway station there. The boy finds out said computer is a piece of junk that never worked in the first place, and its decisions are actually made by an old man who, upon talking to the boy, moves the subway station elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like an adaptation of Robert Munsch's "[Jonathan Cleaned Up — Then He Heard a Sound](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/157626.Jonathan_Cleaned_Up_Then_He_Heard_a_Sound)" (or "Blackberry Subway Jam").  It was made into a short film which you can find on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VaHxXpmFyE).